# Will update my project typescript version affect other packages

Tags: typescript, npm, package.json

I have a project running typescript version 4.0.3. If I want to update the typescript version to 4.3.4, will it affect other packages such as giving error during compilation or build time as well as runtime issue?

Have tried update the version to 4.3.4 but no errors is given out and my project is able to run. However due to full testing of my project is not done, could not justify that project is run without errors

Comment: I believe it does but depends on the packages that you're using.

Comment: Usually no, but if you're worried just do it and roll back if something broke.